# Trouble using elseif php statement

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I'm trying show different images on different pages like this:

```
<?php $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];if (strpos($url,'cart') == true): ?>
Your Cart
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $urlonepage = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];if (strpos($urlonepage,'onepage') == true): ?>
Checkout
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $multishipping = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];if (strpos($multishipping,'multishipping') == true): ?>
Multiple Address Checkout

<?php else: ?>
Everywhere else
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem I'm having is I don't want to show the "Everywhere Else" part on any of the other pages. I tried using elseif but I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  Sometimes takes me a while :)

```
<?php $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
<?php if (strpos($url,'cart') == true): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cartheader')->toHTML(); ?>
<?php elseif (strpos($url,'onepage') == true): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('onepagecheckoutheader')->toHTML(); ?>
<?php elseif (strpos($url,'multishipping') == true): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('multipleaddressheader')->toHTML(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
```

Main Header